# Angular JS Service Architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

EDIT

The short version:
Say I have application data is many different services. How do I get around needing to inject all of those services into every controller that displays application state?

EDIT

I am building my first Angular application. The basic design is I have a home page that shows the value of about 5 different variables (which are each pretty complicated). While on this page the app is collecting and analyzing data from bluetooth. Occasionally, the these 5 variables and some bluetooth data are saved to a REST back end and also saved to the device. There are pages for each of these 5 variables to change their value.

I have done my best to follow best practices. I have very thin controllers. I use services for all my data. I really only use $scope for binding data between views and controllers.

My issue now is that I started with a global "State" service to keep track of those 5 variables. I inject into any controller that needs to display state, and bind the html to it. Any time I want to change any state, I call a method of that State service to do it. This worked well, but now that State service is getting huge.

I have tried to break functions out to other services, but I run into the issue of needing to read data from the State service, then writing back to other properties of the State service. If I inject the other service into State, I can't inject State into the other service too.

I have thought about how I could have many smaller services, but I keep coming back to when I save the data to the server. When I do that I need to gather up data from every corner of the application to send up. If all this information is stored in different services, I am left with injecting all of them into a single service once again.

As I write this, I am pretty sure I am missing a big concept with using $scope across an application.

Any pointers would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Can you list your dependencies between state and sub-state services?

Comment: I recommend clearly stating your problem in 1 or 2 sentences. If you're looking for best practices, this might not be the place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Could you divide things into sub-services, and then make the State service an aggregator for these sub-services, then instead of injecting State into the sub-services, you inject the specific sub-service that you need?  E.g.:

```
var app = angular.module('services', []);

app.service('sub1', function(){

    return {
        // ...
    }
});

app.service('sub2', function(sub1){

    var data = sub1.getData();
    data.prop = 'new_value';
    sub1.setData(data);

    return {
        // ...
    }
});

app.service('State', function(sub1, sub2){

    var data = sub1.getData();
    data.prop = 'new_value';
    sub1.setData(data);

    var data = sub2.getData();
    data.prop = 'new_value';
    sub2.setData(data);

    return {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: With that design, would I then inject State into all my controllers to be able to bind to all the data?

Comment: Yes. It would contain all the necessary calls to access the data from the sub-services.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need Redux to help you manage your application state
https://github.com/wbuchwalter/ng-redux